# Calculation using the date function

Tags: r, date, lubridate

Need to get the sales for every last month of the years.

```
   Month    Sales
01-03-2018  2351
01-06-2018  4522
01-09-2018  3632
01-12-2018  6894
01-03-2019  5469
01-06-2019  6546
01-09-2019  7885
01-12-2019  6597
01-03-2020  7845
01-06-2020  6894
01-09-2020  5469
01-12-2020  6546
01-03-2021  2351
01-06-2021  4522
01-09-2021  3632
01-12-2021  6546
01-03-2022  7885
01-06-2022  6597
01-09-2022  7845
01-12-2022  6894
```

Here i want to find the sales of every 12 months of the year. 
Output should be as follows:

```
Month   Sales
01-12-2018  6894
01-12-2019  6597
01-12-2020  6546
01-12-2021  6546
01-12-2022  6894
```

I can select every forth row from the table, but i want to do it using the Date Function. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your column `Month` is set as a date variable and use `format` to get the month, i.e.

```
#Make sure it is a date variable
df$Month <- as.POSIXct(df$Month, format = '%d-%m-%Y')

df[format(df$Month, '%m') == 12,]
```

which gives,

> ```
>        Month Sales
> 4  2018-12-01  6894
> 8  2019-12-01  6597
> 12 2020-12-01  6546
> 16 2021-12-01  6546
> 20 2022-12-01  6894
> ```

Answer (score 1):

One way with `startsWith`:

```
#Month needs to be of character type
df[startsWith(df$Month, '01-12-'), ]
#        Month Sales
#4  01-12-2018  6894
#8  01-12-2019  6597
#12 01-12-2020  6546
#16 01-12-2021  6546
#20 01-12-2022  6894
```

Comment: Maybe it's worth saying that the variable needs to be a character for this to work